# Waking up a computer from WAN

Tags: home-server, wake-on-lan

I'm looking to design a mechanism that allows me to turn on my home computer remotely without phoning and asking someone to press the big power button.

Currently, a computer can get awake with a special Wakeup-on-LAN message directed to its Ethernet card's MAC address. But that can happen only on LAN.

I currently have an ISP-provided home router (Vodafone Station 2, could be a `SGH 1500`, as some ebayers say) that supports virtual servers, DMZ, dynamic DNS and other things. But it doesn't have an authenticated wakeup-on-LAN service.

### Possible solution

Use DynDNS to assign a hostname to the station, forward a port to a PC kept 24/7 alive with a simple home-made web interface that authenticates me and sends the WOL packet to the target computer. But this **nullifies** the word "energy saving"

### Possible alternate

Buying a Raspberry PI and keeping it alive with its minimal consumption. The web interface must be able to run on it (run its own webserver or inside Tomcat/Mono depends on available performance)

### Question

Are these two the only solution to the problem? Does anyone know an open source computer-awaker software that runs on HTTP?

Comment: I'm using [dd-wrt](http://www.dd-wrt.com/) at home on my wifi router connected to wan. It eats no more than 5W and it can serve to any of those solutions and can send WOL. It's an alternative firmware for soho devices. Other device that crossing my mind is from Mikrotik [RB750](http://routerboard.com/RB750), simple router with complex system (2.5W<) or practically the same thing with wifi [RB951-2n](http://routerboard.com/RB951-2n).

Comment: Is a dd-wrt supporting router cheaper than Raspberry (~50€)? I'm not the owner of the home gateway, so I can't modify its firmware

Comment: Don't know exactly, I'm using 70eur Wrt160nl because of reasonably speed procesor and usb port, but maybe there are some cheaper than 50. You can find [Supported models Here](http://dd-wrt.com/site/support/router-database), it's good to read all that you can about device you wan't to use with dd-wrt, because there are somethimes compatibility issues.